# How to vectorize this in R

Tags: r

I have two tables of data on traffic flow. I'm trying to (eventually) combine them into a linear progression plot of traffic by milepost. Example:

```
mileposts <- structure(list(city = c("city1", "city2", "city3", "city4"), 
milepost = c(0L, 50L, 120L, 250L)), .Names = c("city", "milepost"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4"))

   city milepost
1 city1        0
2 city2       50
3 city3      120
4 city4      250


traffic <- structure(list(citypair = c("city1-city2", "city2-city4", "city1-city3", 
"city1-city4", "city3-city4"), traffic = c(610L, 23L, 139L, 88L, 
17L), origmp = c(0L, 50L, 0L, 0L, 120L), destmp = c(50L, 250L, 
120L, 250L, 250L)), .Names = c("citypair", "traffic", "origmp", 
"destmp"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5"))

   citypair        traffic   origmp  destmp
1 city1-city2        610      0       50
2 city2-city4        23       50      250
3 city1-city3       139       0       120
4 city1-city4        88       0       250
5 city3-city4        17       120     250
```

What I would like is to add to the 'mileposts' table, a column 'volume' that lists all the traffic beginning at or passing through that city (the cities go in order from 1-2-3-4). For example, city3's volume would be the sum of values from traffic[c(2, 4, 5),2].

How can I do this? I know it must be some sort of for loop. I tried a loop that adds the value in `traffic$traffic to mileposts$vol` conditional on `traffic$origmp[i] >= mileposts$milepost` and `traffic$destmp[i] <= mileposts$milepost`, but I got the error saying `"the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"`. However if I wrap the whole thing around a `[j]` dimension on `mileposts$milepost`, the whole run becomes incredibly slow. Any suggestions on how to speed this up/code efficiently?

More generally, I guess I am asking how to perform conditional operations using data between two data frames, in an efficient manner (i.e. not looping through every line of both data frames). Thank you!

Comment: How exactly are we supposed to know all the cities "beginning at or passing through that city."?

Comment: @IShouldBuyABoat - i'm making a big assumption of city1-city2-city3-city4 : this should ideally be specified to make it a generalisable solution though.

Comment: @thelatemail Yes, they go in order from city1-4. Sorry for not being more clear.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit convoluted, but it works:

```
cityorder <- c("city1","city2","city3","city4")
through <- lapply(strsplit(traffic$citypair,"-"),match,cityorder)
through <- lapply(through,function(x) seq(x[1],x[2]-1))

citymatch <- sapply(mileposts$city, grep, cityorder)
sum.ids <- lapply(citymatch, function(x)  sapply(through, function(y) x %in% y) )
mileposts$traffic <- sapply(sum.ids, function(x) sum(traffic$traffic[x]) )

#   city milepost traffic
#1 city1        0     837
#2 city2       50     250
#3 city3      120     128
#4 city4      250       0
```

The results check out with the intended result "*city3's volume would be the sum of values from* traffic[c(2, 4, 5),2]"

```
sum(traffic[c(2, 4, 5),2])
#[1] 128
```

Answer (score 0):

With your two tables - `mileposts` and `traffic` already in memory, I can get the result you want with the code below -

```
library(data.table)

# building index of which route traffic is to be associated with which city
uniquecities <- unique(mileposts$milepost)
uniqueCityCombns <- data.table(expand.grid(uniquecities,uniquecities,uniquecities))
setnames(uniqueCityCombns, c('origmp','destmp','milepost'))
uniqueCityCombns <- uniqueCityCombns[origmp < destmp & milepost < destmp]
uniqueCityCombns <- data.table(uniqueCityCombns <- uniqueCityCombns[origmp <= milepost])

# calculating traffic passing through the city
uniqueCityCombnsTrf <- merge(uniqueCityCombns,traffic, by = c('origmp','destmp'))
uniqueCityCombnsTrf <- uniqueCityCombnsTrf [,list(traffic = sum(traffic)), by = 'milepost']
uniqueCityCombnsTrf <- merge(uniqueCityCombnsTrf , mileposts, by = 'milepost')
```

Output -

```
> uniqueCityCombnsTrf 
   milepost traffic  city
1:        0     837 city1
2:       50     250 city2
3:      120     128 city3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
traffic$start  <-  as.numeric(gsub("city|-city.+$", "", traffic$citypair) )
traffic$end    <-  as.numeric(gsub("city[[:digit:]]*|-city", "", traffic$citypair) )
sapply(mileposts$city, function(cit) {n=as.numeric(sub("city","",cit))
                    sum(traffic$traffic*( (n >= traffic$start) & n < traffic$end) )} )
#---------
city1 city2 city3 city4 
  837   250   128     0
```